# Octave gradient descent for linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, octave, linear-regression

I've been strugeling to complete the extra problems on a coursera course.

It's multiple variable linear regression with gradient descent.

I have completed the exercise using a normal equation which provides correct answers but when I use gradient descent it seems to increase theta way too much.

The problem cant be fixed by changing the number of itterations or the learning rate.

```
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters
  theta = theta - alpha / m * ((X * theta - y)'* X)';
  J_history(iter) = computeCostMulti(X, y, theta);
end
end
```

The results I got for theta with normal equation are:

```
89597.909543,

 139.210674

 -8738.019112.
```

But with gradient descent I get:

```
334302.063993

 100087.116006

 3673.548451
```

Comment: It seems that your code is correct. Is your `costFunction` decrease during the for loop?  Please add more information about what you have tried to do, like changing the learning rate or the number of iterations. In addition, maybe you missed something else, did you add `ones(m, 1)` to your `X` matrix?

Comment: Moreover, gradient descent may find a local optimum. Try initialize theta randomly, it will change the start point of the algorithm and may help.